# How to send a Hashmap as a field inside a document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, hashmap

I have generated a map `dataMap` in JS and it is looks like below on console:

```
dataMap: { val1 → "50", item1 → "shoe", val2 → "20", item2 → "book" }
```

When I was trying to write it onto cloud Firestore with

```
        db.collection("readDynamic").add({
            name: 'Alex',
            items: dataMap,
            age: '24'
        })
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
            if (querySnapshot.size) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (data) {
                    console.log("Document successfully updated!");
                    console.log(data.id, " => ", data.data());
                });

            }
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log("error!", error);
        })
```

It gives error:

*Uncaught FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Map object*

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you're using for `dataMap` isn't supported by the Firestore SDK.  It won't accept ES6 Map type objects.  You will have to convert it to a regular JavaScript object first.  For example, this should work:

```
const dataMap = {
    val1: 50,
    item1: "shoe",
    val2: "20",
    item2: "book"
}
```