# Firestore transaction update does not use FirestoreDataConverter

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I want do update a document of a type "Rabbit" inside a transaction:

```
type Rabbit = {
    id: string;
    map: Map<string, string>;
}

const converter = {
    toFirestore: (data: Partial<Rabbit>): firestore.DocumentData => {
        const doc = {...data, map: Object.fromEntries(data.map!)} as firestore.DocumentData;
        delete doc.id;
        return doc;
    },
    fromFirestore: (snap: firestore.DocumentSnapshot) => ({
        id: snap.id,
        ...snap.data(),
    }) as unknown as Rabbit,
}

const docRef = collection("rabbits").withConverter(converter).doc("id");
transaction.update(docRef, { map: new Map() });
```

This throws the following error:

> FirebaseError: Function Transaction.update() called with invalid data.
> Unsupported field value: a custom Map object

Why is the converter's "toFirestore" method not used when processing the transaction.update()?

Comment: This says that the converter should be set outside the transaction scope. Not sure why... https://stackoverflow.com/a/66105253/294949

Comment: That answer wasn't working for me. My ref with converter is created outside the transaction and .get() is using fromFirestore(), but .update() is not using toFirestore().

Answer (score 0):

Adding some insights in the previous comment mentioning a possible cause for this transaction to fail, the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transaction_failure) states:

> A transaction can fail for the following reasons:
>
> - The transaction read a document that was modified outside of the transaction. In this case, the transaction automatically runs again. The transaction is retried a finite number of times.

But I believe that the map object your are generating `{ map: new Map() }` is not valid. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63179559/7757976) it is stated that the Firestore SDK won't accept [ES6 Map type objects](https://medium.com/swlh/es6-map-object-6663ed1410f7). Thus you might need to change the way you are passing this field `{ map: new Map() }` as this is producing the `Unsupported field value: a custom Map object`